# Local variable sum previous columns

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to use @variable1 + @variable2 into a query but is actually given 0 as result.

MariaDB
Server Version: 10.2.21

```sql
set @start_at = '2019-01-01';
set @end_at = '2019-01-16';
set @receivable = 0;
set @invoiced = 0;
SELECT DISTINCT Customer.custnr 'Customer Number',
                Address.name    'Name',
                @receivable := sum(case
                      WHEN [condition1 <= @start_at]
                        AND Transactions.`key` not in [subquery]
                        THEN Transactions.amount
                      ELSE 0 END) 'Account Receivable',
                @invoiced := sum(case
                      WHEN [condition1 between @start_at and @end_at]
                        AND [condition2]
                        AND [condition3]
                        AND Transactions.`key` not in [subquery]
                        THEN Transactions.amount
                      ELSE 0 END) 'Invoiced',
                @receivable + @invoiced 'Total'
FROM LocalCust
       INNER JOIN Customer
                  on Customer.`key` = LocalCust.customerkey
       INNER JOIN Address
                  on Address.`key` = Customer.addresskey
       INNER JOIN Location
                  on Location.`key` = LocalCust.localkey
       INNER JOIN Transactions
                  on Transactions.localcustkey = LocalCust.`Key`
GROUP BY Transactions.localcustkey;
```

Result:
[image: Result from query]

Comment: your screenshot doesn't match to the query. there is no `Route` column in query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery and don't use variables at all:

```
SELECT x.*, (Account_Receivable + Invoice) as Total
FROM (SELECT c.custnr as Customer_Number, a.name, 
             sum(case when condition1 <= @start_at and
                           t.`key` not in [subquery]
                      then t.amount
                      else 0 
                 end) as Account_Receivable,
             sum(case when condition1 between @start_at and @end_at and
                           [condition2] and
                           [condition3] and
                           t.`key` not in [subquery]
                      then t.amount
                      else 0 
                 end) as Invoiced
      FROM LocalCust lc JOIN
           Customer c
           on c.`key` = lc.customerkey JOIN
           Address a
           on a.`key` = c.addresskey JOIN
           Location l
           on l.`key` = lc.localkey join
           Transactions t
           on t.localcustkey = lc.`Key`
      GROUP BY c.custnr, a.name
     ) x;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never needed with `GROUP BY`.
- The `GROUP BY` keys should match the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.
- Choose column aliases that do not need to be escaped.  That is, no spaces.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can not just put @receivable, @invoiced and @receivable + @invoiced in the same select statement. (They will not store the value in order. They will be executed at the same time.)

First, You need to store the values in @receivable, @invoiced then use a subquery to calculate the total:

```
set @start_at = '2019-01-01';
set @end_at = '2019-01-16';
set @receivable = 0;
set @invoiced = 0;

SELECT *, A.[Account Receivable] + A.[Invoiced]  AS TOTAL FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT Customer.custnr 'Customer Number',
                Address.name    'Name',
                @receivable := sum(case
                      WHEN [condition1 <= @start_at]
                        AND Transactions.`key` not in [subquery]
                        THEN Transactions.amount
                      ELSE 0 END) 'Account Receivable',
                @invoiced := sum(case
                      WHEN [condition1 between @start_at and @end_at]
                        AND [condition2]
                        AND [condition3]
                        AND Transactions.`key` not in [subquery]
                        THEN Transactions.amount
                      ELSE 0 END) 'Invoiced'
FROM LocalCust
       INNER JOIN Customer
                  on Customer.`key` = LocalCust.customerkey
       INNER JOIN Address
                  on Address.`key` = Customer.addresskey
       INNER JOIN Location
                  on Location.`key` = LocalCust.localkey
       INNER JOIN Transactions
                  on Transactions.localcustkey = LocalCust.`Key`
GROUP BY Transactions.localcustkey) A;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!